# Send Firebase Notification using Java, not FCM Console

Tags: java, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am adding notifications to my android application, but I can't seem to send a notification via my java code. I am getting back a 200 http code form the response, but nothing shows up.

This works on the Firebase console itself, but once I try to use my Java code, thing happens.

This is my code below

```
package actions.authentication;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.Action;

import edocs.actions.PublicAction;
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;

public class SendPushNotification extends PublicAction {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8022560668279505764L;

    // Method to send Notifications from server to client end.
    public final static String AUTH_KEY_FCM = "SERVER_KEY_HERE";
    public final static String API_URL_FCM = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
    public final static String DEVICE_ID = "DEVICE_TOKEN_HERE";

    public String execute() {
        String DeviceIdKey = DEVICE_ID;
        String authKey = AUTH_KEY_FCM;
        String FMCurl = API_URL_FCM;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(FMCurl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=" + authKey);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            System.out.println(DeviceIdKey);
            JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
            data.put("to", DeviceIdKey.trim());
            JSONObject info = new JSONObject();
            info.put("title", "FCM Notificatoin Title"); // Notification title
            info.put("body", "Hello First Test notification"); // Notification body
            data.put("data", info);
            System.out.println(data.toString());
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(data.toString());
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            return Action.SUCCESS;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        return Action.SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

The line `System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);` prints out the following

> Response Code : 200

Has anyone else had this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code works for me.  Add the line noted below to see what the full response status is.  Post the ouput.

```
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        System.out.println("Resonse: " + response); // <= ADD THIS
```

Also, if you want Firebase to generate the notification for you, the `body` and `title` need to be properties of `notification`, not `data`. Details are in [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications).

```
        info.put("title", "FCM Notification Title"); // Notification title
        info.put("body", "Hello First Test notification"); // Notification body
        data.put("notification", info); // <= changed from "data"
```

Comment: YES! It worked! It makes sense that you have to push in the info into the notification. Thank you so much!